# Docker compose unable to access one service from another due to dynamic IP

Tags: docker-compose, service, redis, ip, docker-network

I am running docker on Windows WSL2. I have the following docker compose that starts up redis and then another service(*serviceA*) that depends on redis. I need to run a script after serviceA starts up. This script needs to access redis from inside *serviceA-cont*.

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  redis-service:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis-cont                
    ports:
      - "6379" 
      
  serviceA:
    depends_on:
      - redis-service
    container_name: serviceA-cont    
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: scripts/customscript.js
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    stdin_open: true
```

Using docker network inspect, I found that redis service's IP keeps changing on every docker compose build. This means I have to keep changing redis service's IP in the custom script manually everytime I run docker compose. How do I handle this in a cleaner way? I tried creating a custom network and assigning it to each service, but I see the following error:

```
service "redis-service" refers to undefined network "network-name": invalid compose project
```

Setting network_mode:host on redis service throws this error:

```
network mode "network-name" not supported by buildkit
```

Comment: why not using service-name directly instead of ip?

Comment: Looks like this works. Thanks! If you want to add your solution as an answer, I can accept it.